# How to convert a float value in to Min:Sec

Tags: objective-c

i'm trying to convert my second in min:sec. My code is:

```
- (IBAction)calcola:(id)sender 
{
    float grandezzaKB= [[fieldGrandezza text] floatValue];
    float velocitaMbps= [[fieldVelocita text] floatValue] ;
    float grandezzaMB= grandezzaKB*1000;
    float velocitakB = velocitaMbps*128;
    float secondiTotali = grandezzaMB/velocitakB;
    float min = secondiTotali / 60;

    NSString *risultato = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f minuti" ,min];

    [labelRisultato setText:risultato];
}
```

Sorry if it isn't english but i'm italian :D Someone can help me?
i've already tried with the mod but it doesn't work with float :(
Sorry if the code isn't perfect, but i'm a newbie :)

Comment: Shouldn't float grandezzaMB= grandezzaKB*1000; be float grandezzaMB= grandezzaKB*1024; ?

Comment: Can you post the output you desire and the output you are currently getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry but I'm not sure I understand you but if you want to convert time in seconds to format min:sec you can use:

```
float timeInSecond = 65.0f;
int time = (int)timeInSecond;

int seconds = time % 60;
int minutes = (time / 60) % 60;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d", minutes, seconds];
```

Please let me know if you are asking about something else so I will remove my answer.